# ActiveMQ jolokia gives different message response depending on environment

Tags: bash, activemq-classic, jolokia

I have to get (not consume) part of a message that is in queue. I reused bash script that was prompted as a response here, with the use of */api/jolokia/* : [ActiveMQ Jolokia API How can I get the full Message Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27707190/activemq-jolokia-api-how-can-i-get-the-full-message-body)

Part of a response that I am interested to get is ***MsgId*** in ***value:text*** :

```
"request": {
    "mbean": "org.apache.activemq:brokerName=MyBrokerName,destinationName=MyQueueName,destinationType=Queue,type=Broker",
    "type": "exec",
    "operation": "browseMessages()"
},
"value": [
    {
        "jMSCorrelationIDAsBytes": [],
        ***some other objects here ***
        "text": "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n<RepositoryOperationRq xmlns=\"http://www.ACORD.org/\">\r\n  <MsgId>xxx28bab-e62c-4dbc-a2aa-xxx</MsgId>\r\n  <CreationDtTime>2020-01-01T11:11:11-11:00</CreationDtTime>\r\n
```

There is no problem on DEV env ActiveMQ but when I tried do the same on UAT env ActiveMQ there is no ***value:text*** object in response at all, and some others objects values are different, like:

```
"connectionControl": false
```

and

```
"connectionControl": "false"
```

I thought it might be because of ***maxDepth*** parameter so I increased it. Unfortunately when set maxDepth=5 I got that error:

```
"error_type": "java.lang.IllegalStateException",
"error": "java.lang.IllegalStateException : Error while extracting next from org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.FilePendingMessageCursor@3bb9ace4",
"status": 500
```

and the whole ActiveMQ stopped receiving any messages- had to force restart it. ActiveMQ configs should be the same on both envs, and the version is 5.13.3. Do you know why that *text* object is missing?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your comments. You are probably right about that the message content may be different, unfortunately I cannot make any changes to message content itself, it is external incoming soap message.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question please mark it as correct to help other users who have the same question in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference here is down to the *content* of the messages in each environment. The `browseMessages` operation simply returns the messages in the corresponding destination (e.g. `MyQueueName`).

If the message is not a `javax.jms.TextMessage` then it won't have the `text` field. If a property is `false` instead of `"false"` that just means the property value was a `boolean` instead of a `String` respectively.